# mysql order and groupby

Tags: sql, mysql

I got a MySQL table of logs. It has the following fields: id, status_id, object_id, created, modified.

I'm wondering what's the best way to get the latest status for each object?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My last solution was to do

```
SELECT id, status_id, object_id, created, modified 
FROM (SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY created DESC) AS a
GROUP BY object_id
```

It works but I think there's a better way of doing this. Anyone care to enlighten us here at SO? :)

Comment: is the status_id a foreign key reference to another table containing statuses?

Comment: What SQL have you gotten so far? What are the issues with it?

Comment: Ah, I see now, this is a table detailing the statuses an object has over a period of time. Sorry, it's early.

Comment: what's the difference between id and object_id?  I'm assuming you don't have a (relevant) PK in the table?

Answer (score 2):

try this, i've not checked this but should work

```
select object_id, status_id, MAX(created)
from ff
group by object_id having created = MAX(created)
```

the key is to use `having` function which will choose last item for every grouped object

EDIT:

I added `status_id` to select ;)

Comment: Weird man, I'm getting: Unknown column created in HAVING clause

Comment: do you have `created` column in your table? you can try to reverse it: `MAX(created) = created`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for

```
SELECT status_id FROM logs WHERE object_id = xx ORDER BY modified DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

If you have another table with status codes, you can use

```
SELECT status_code FROM logs, status_codes_table
WHERE status_code_id = status_id AND object_id = xx
ORDER BY modified DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

**Edit**:

If you want to have a table of all objects and their latest status codes, you can use:

```
SELECT object_id, status_id
FROM logs
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING modified = MAX(modified)
```

Comment: your last solution which I was looking for does not work either :( still getting the Unknown column modified in HAVING clause error