# How to orderby before groupby by mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I find the question at [mysql order and groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306810/mysql-order-and-groupby)

but it not works,

I get the same solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM user 
    ORDER BY create_time DESC
) AS user 
GROUP BY user.role
```

to implement list the newest user of each role

but mysql's view can't work with subselect.

Comment: *"mysql's view can't work with subselect."*: I have never heard of such a restriction. Is `user` a view or do you want to create a view based on the select?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't support a first/last function

The answer in the link you provided, is based on the face that HAVING will pick the last item:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
GROUP BY user.role
HAVING  create_time = MAX(create_time)
```