# SQL order by, group by, having

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm using a database to store results of an election with the columns id, candidate, post_time and result. Results are put in the database during 'counting the votes'. When a new update is available, a new entry will be inserted.

From this database, I would like to create a table with the most recent results (`MAX post_time`) per candidate (`GROUP BY` candidate), ordered by result (`ORDER BY` result).

How can I translate this to a working SQL-statement?

(I've tried [mysql order and groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306810/mysql-order-and-groupby) without success)

I've tried:

```
SELECT *, MAX(time_post) 
FROM [database] 
GROUP BY candidate 
HAVING MAX(time_post) = time_post 
ORDER BY result
```

Comment: you should post what you have tried, you might be close and people can direct you to fix what you already have.

Comment: I've tried this: SELECT *, MAX(time_post) FROM [database] GROUP BY candidate HAVING MAX(time_post) = time_post ORDER BY result

(also time_post = MAX(time_post) in reverse order)

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause MUST contain ALL fields in the `SELECT` that are not into an aggregate function ( MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG)

Comment: is `result` different for different `post_time` ?

Comment: @LucM: This ("MUST") is not true for MySQL. If you group by the Primary Key, it may be good for performance, too. It can lead to error results though, from incorrect use, as in the example.

Comment: @Shiplu: Yes, a new database entry on a certain 'post_time' contains a new 'result'. I would like to display the latest result.

Comment: @ypercube I don't know mysql. Can you select a field and not specifying it into the group by clause ? The OP is doing that by `SELECT *` and only specifyng candidate in `group by`

Comment: Show the schema of the table. Is there any primary/unique key?

Comment: @LucM: Yes, you can. See: [MySQL docs, GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: @ypercube Thank you to contribute to my education :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have multiple results per candidate at same time, next should work:

```
select r.candiate, r.result
from results r
inner join (
    select candidate, max(post_time) as ptime
    from results
    group by candidate 
) r2 on r2.candiate=r.candidate and r2.ptime=r.post_time
order by r.result
```

Comment: `group by` and `from` are the wrong way round in the subquery.

Comment: @Shiplu: True, but in this case no problem. One person is filling in the results and inserting new results via a web form.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `MAX` will not select the *record* with the maximum time, but it will select the maximum *value* from *any* record. So

```
SELECT MAX(a), MAX(b) FROM example
```

where exmple contains the two records `a=1, b=2` and `a=4, b=0`, will result in `a=4, b=2`, which wasn't in the data. You should probably create a *view* with the latest votes only from each candidate, then query that. For performance, it may be sensible to use a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

Is the post_time likely to be the same for all the most recent results? Also does each candidate only appear once per post_time?

This could be achieved by just using a SELECT statement. Is there a reason you need the results in a new table?

If each candidate only appears once per post_time:

```
SELECT candidate, result
FROM table
WHERE post_time = (SELECT MAX(post_time) FROM table)
```

If you want to count how many times a candidate appears in the table for the last post_time:

```
SELECT candidate, count(result) as ResultCount
FROM table
WHERE post_time = (SELECT MAX(post_time) FROM table)
GROUP BY candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

By what i see from ur attempts i'd think you should use this

```
SELECT MAX(post_time) FROM `table` GROUP BY candidate ORDER BY result
```

but the MAX statment only return a single value therefore i dont see why ORDER BY would be needed.

if you want multiple results try looking up the TOP statment

Answer (score 0):

One way (tied results shown):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT candidate 
           , MAX(time_post) AS time_post
      FROM tableX
      GROUP BY candidate 
    ) AS m
    ON (m.candidate, m.time_post) = (t.candidate, t.time_post)
ORDER BY t.result
```

and another one (no ties, only one row per candidate shown):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
      ( SELECT DICTINCT candidate
        FROM tableX
      ) AS d
  JOIN 
      tableX AS t
    ON t.PK =                  --- the Primary Key of the table, here
       ( SELECT ti.PK          --- and here
         FROM tableX AS ti
         WHERE ti.candidate = d.candidate
         ORDER ti.time_post DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) 
ORDER BY t.result
```